# Now that part of the .NET Framework runs on Mac and Linux, how can we know if a .NET app will run outside of Windows?

Tags: .net, cross-platform

I think, somehow the .net apps should be able to find out, on which OS are they running.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your app runs fine on .NET Core 5 in Windows (not full .NET Framework), then by definition it should run on .NET Core 5 on OS X and Linux.

However that's still too optimistic, as file paths and so on are still different enough to impact the way you write your code. Thorough testing is always needed.